# Retrieving p-value from anderson-darling test (ad.test) in R from an aggregate call

Tags: r

So I have the following

```
ad_test_by_group = aggregate(data, by = group, FUN = "ad.test")
```

and this outputs the test statistic by group. However I would like the p-values associated to each of the group instead.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could use: library("nortest"); apply(data, 2, function(data) {ad.test(data)$p.value})

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ed_sans, you may try:

```
library(nortest)
data(iris)
aggregate(. ~ Species, data = iris[,c(1,5)], function(x) ad.test(x)$p.value)
     Species Sepal.Length
1     setosa    0.3352439
2 versicolor    0.4332962
3  virginica    0.1475325
```

The 2nd column are pvalues.

```
x<-iris[iris$Species=="setosa", 1]
ad.test(x)$p.value
[1] 0.3352439
```